# Using Scanner to test if a line is a comment

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to scan through a .ppm file. I need to disregard lines that start with "#". How would I do this using scanner?
If I do this

```
while((fileScanner.nextLine()).charAt(0)=='#'){
        //Go to next line
    }
```

Then if that line does not begin with a comment, then I skipped that line, and can't go back to get the relevant data in that line.
Anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: `!=` is all you need.

Comment: oh wow, now I feel dumb. Thanks

Comment: Side note: this question made me smile because I've written code that already does this for a piece of software I'm working on.

Comment: But, would that not move to the next line anyway? I'm kinda confused how asking in the while statement doesn't move the stream forward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
    if (line.startsWith("#")) {
        continue;
    }
    // Go to next line
}
```

The above is a more adequate pattern. When the file would end with a comment the original code is a bit problematic. Also lines can be empty, so that a charAt will not do.

Comment: Thank you, this solved the whole problem very nicely

Comment: So if the line does not start with a comment, I would need to parse the line variable for int values? (The comments would be on the second line, right before the image dimensions)

Comment: I could not formulate it any better. "Go to next line" being the place for any processing of a non-comment line.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at your while loop.

`while((fileScanner.nextLine()).charAt(0)=='#'){`

You're saying ***"scan the next line, and if the first character is a '#', execute the loop body"***.

This approach has a few problems:

1. It will this stop looping as soon as you don't find a comment.
2. None of the lines are being stored in a variable, they just get thrown away.

Instead of reading from the file within your conditional statement, why don't you take advantage of the `continue` statement?

```
while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
    if (line.charAt(0) == '#') {
        continue; // Found a comment, so skip this iteration.
    } else {
        // Do whatever you want with your non-comment line.
    }
}
```

Note: Some comments may have spaces in front of them, e.g. `" # comment"`. I'm assuming you don't care about those.